# WAMP won't start after installing WAMP with PHP 7 support

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I had WampServer (PHP 5.5.1 usw) installed, it was running fine. Today I installed a newer version of WAMP with PHP 7 support. Unfortunately, now both versions of WAMP won't start anymore.
The WAMP-icon changes from red to yellow, and the startup process seems to halt.
The older WAMP installation is located in c:/wamp, the newer in c:/wamp64.

Do these two WAMP-versions interfere with each other? I can't start none of them.

Kind regards,
Milan

Comment: They should not interfere, but it does depend upon which versions you are trying to install together. And of course you cannot run them together as bot Apache's try to use port 80 and both MYSQL's try to use port 3306

Comment: Also are both versions 64bit or is the original in `C:/wamp` a 32 bit version of WAMPServer

Comment: Also if you have added anything in the wamp folder structure to the PATH that will also cause issues.